# best method to search/recognize sublist inside a list, allowing insertion

Tags: python, list, matching

using Python, i would like to match all the sublist inside a list that may fill a particular pattern,

for example :

```
 l = ['dummy', ',', 'as', 'it', 'is', 'an', 'example', '.', 
     'as', 'we', 'assume', 'it', 'is', '.', 
      'as', 'to', 'do', 'some', '.']

 sublist = ['as', '*', 'it']
```

and

`mySub(l, sublist)` provide  => `[['as', 'it'], ['as', 'we', 'assume', 'it'], ['as', 'it', 'is', 'an', 'example', '.', 'as', 'we', 'assume', 'it']]`

or others examples:

`mySub(l, ['as', '*', 'it', '*', 'example'])` provide  => `[['as', 'it', 'is', 'an', 'example'], ]`
`mySub(l, ['as', '*', 'it', 'is'])` provide  => `[['as', 'it', 'is'],  ['as', 'it', 'is', 'an', 'example', '.', 'as', 'we', 'assume', 'it', 'is'], ['as', 'we', 'assume', 'it', 'is']]`

actually my problem is more complicated because `l` will be list of list, and `sublist` will also have to match some part of it on a rank basis. But this is to schematize the main difficulty i have that is how to do this kind of efficient matching with using Python. (so solving this probleme with some simple regexp matching will not help me)

please see that '*' is a like for regular expression, meaning that we may jump some items.
also even if not clear, i need to have all possible sublists, that why some are repeated with greedy like matching.

please if any of you have any clues /links / interesting thoughts

best regards

(i remember of some algorithm about matching with bioinformatic/dna sequence but were not able to find it again)

Comment: What are the possible formats of `sublist` ?

Comment: well i jsut have added a '*' to materialize something like * in regular pattern, that is match/allow any [0 to n] sub item. This much more the idea and to show that is not only 'finding exact' sublists inside a list.

Comment: You could build an NFA from the sublist and then scan the main list. Every time you end up in an accepting state you output the path that lead there.

Comment: @Bakuriu, it may helps me, have you got a sample or any links about this NFA?

Comment: I mean [Nondeterministic Finite Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton). It's more or less one way to implement regular expressions. In your case you'd have one node for each element in the sublist. Normal nodes point to the following element of the sublist, while the `*` special node must be able to match any sequence, thus it should point both to the next token and itself. Everytime you reach the last token of the sublist you output the path that lead there. It isn't trivial, but shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to sequence aligment in biology , which is most frequently solved by Dynamic programming methods. Also you can look at pattern matching algorithms used in NLP, the Natural Language Toolkit (nltk) should discuss some related problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = set(l)
s2 = set(sublist)
s1.intersection(s2)
[out]set(['as', 'it'])
```

Comment: it does no allow the insertion of possible. i am not looking for common parts but for sommon sublist that start and end like the one provided. I am going to edit to show other examples